# Email-register C# does not register but send the email

Tags: c#, asp.net

My register page worked fine before I added method for sending an email.  After that, I am able to press the register button to create a new user but the details are not saved anymore even though the email is sent.  Why it does not save? I am placing both methods for saving and send email:

```
static async Task Execute()
    {
        string apiKey = "API KEY";
        var client = new SendGridClient("DWADwdwdgfeg3efwfewgseg");
        var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
        var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
        var to = new EmailAddress("miroslav.stojanov@gmail.com", "Example User");
        var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
        var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }


[HttpPost]
[Route("Authorisation/Registration/Save")]
[Transactional]
public JsonResult Save(User eUser, Request eRequest)
{

    Execute().Wait();

    try
    {
        //Look at it later
        eUser.Password = EncryptHelper.EncryptString(eUser.Password, "kahat");
        eUser.Password1 = EncryptHelper.EncryptString(eUser.Password1, "kahat123");
        this.rpGeneric.SaveOrUpdate<User>(eUser);
        this.rpGeneric.SaveOrUpdate<Request>(eRequest);
        return GetAll();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ThrowJsonError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I comment the Execute().Wait(); inside of the Save method then I am able to save but not able to send message, any ideas?

Comment: Do not call `.Wait()` on a task. That's a giant red flag that you've done something wrong. You need to await the results, and mark your transaction method as async.

Comment: Ok I will delete it now and I will try again and will let you know what is the output.

Comment: Now Visual Studio says that I have to add await in from of execute: await Execute();

Comment: Yep, That's what I said. You need to await the results.

Comment: Thanks, Mason now it works fine, I receive email and also I can save the details of the user but why there is curly underline of the Execute(); ? Now Visual Studio puts green curly underline if you know what I mean but it works.

Comment: Well, what does it tell you when you hover over it?

Comment: Thank you mason you are awesome, thank you a lot!!! I did it. when I put await Execute(), then I had to do my Save method to be async and it worked like this: public async Task<JsonResult> SaveAsync(User eUser, Request eRequest)
        {

            await Execute();

Answer (score 1):

```
public await Task<JsonResult> Save(User eUser, Request eRequest)
{
    await Execute();

    try
    {
        //Look at it later
        eUser.Password = EncryptHelper.EncryptString(eUser.Password, "kahat");
        eUser.Password1 = EncryptHelper.EncryptString(eUser.Password1, "kahat123");
        this.rpGeneric.SaveOrUpdate<User>(eUser);
        this.rpGeneric.SaveOrUpdate<Request>(eRequest);
        return GetAll();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ThrowJsonError(ex);
    }
}
```

Do not call `.Wait()` on tasks in most circumstances. Instead, mark your method as async and `await` the results of the call.

Comment: Yes man that is perfect answer.. I did it the same thanks I vote for you!